# Corrupted offset in call instruction

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-c++, corruption

The last few days have been spent debugging a very strange problem.  An application built for i386 running on Windows crashed, with the top of the callstack completely corrupted and the instruction pointer in a nonsense location.

After some effort, I rebuilt the callstack and was able to determine how the IP ended up in the nonsense location.  An instruction in boost shared pointer code attempts to call a function defined in my DLLs import address table using an incorrect offset.  The instruction looks like:

```
call dword ptr [nonsense offset into import address table]
```

As a result, execution ended up in a bad location that was, unfortunately, executable.  Execution then proceeded, gobbling up the top of the stack until eventually crashing.

By launching the identical application on my PC, and stepping into the problematic code, I can find the same call instruction and see it's supposed to by calling msvc100's 'new' operator.

Further comparing the minidump from the client's PC to my PC, I found that my PC was calls a function with an offset of 0x0254 into the address table.  On the clients PC, the code is trying to invoke a function with an offset of 0x8254.

What's even more confusing is that this offset is not coming from a register or another memory location.  The offset is a constant in the disassembly.  So, the disassembly looks like:

```
call dword ptr [ 0x50018254 ]
```

not like:

```
call dword ptr [ edx ]
```

Does anyone know how this might happen?

Comment: You have discovered ASLR, Address Space Layout Randomization.  A feature designed to make it difficult for malware to patch a program.  Look for the more typical cause of a problem like that: a stack buffer overflow that destroyed the stack frame and overwrote the return address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a single bit flip:

```
0x0254 = 0b0000001001010100
0x8254 = 0b1000001001010100
```

Perhaps corrupt memory, corrupt disk, gamma ray from the sun...?

If this specific case is reproducible and their on-disk binary matches yours, I'd investigate further.  If it's not specifically reproducible, I'd encourage the client to run some machine diagnostics.

Comment: A co-worker of mine was reproducing what appeared to be an identical crash on his PC, which then proceeded to stop happening.  We were thinking bad memory as well until that happened.  I'm not an expert with how Windows loads DLLs and populates the address used in the call instruction, so I'm not sure through what means it may become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Thats seems to me a hardware error for sure, mainly memory error. As @Hostile_Fork pointed out, is just a bit flip.

Does your memory have ECC feature? it it does it, make sure is enabled. I would pass a burn-in memory test with memtest86 to see what happens, I bet you have a faulty memory chip, doesn't look like a bug.